# How to use __built_in_return_address properly

Tags: gcc

I am having a debugging function where i am using __built_in_return_address

as

```
__built_in_return_address(4); 
__built_in_return_address(3);
__built_in_return_address(2);
__built_in_return_address(1);
```

The compiler throws warnings like:
Unsupported argument for __built_in_return_address for the above lines.

As a temporary solution i am using 
`__built_in_return_address(0);`

this compiles successfully but is not accepted by the team.

I searched for this on :
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html

but still got no clue how to use it without getting unsupported arugments warning.

can anyone please help?

Comment: What's your target architecture? Could you amend your question with more information?

Comment: @FlorianWeimer hI, My basic requirement is to fetch 4 addresses from the stack down to up. I tried using `backTrace()` but execInfo.h is not defined for the platform. Any idea?

Comment: Again, what is your platform? Please include this information in your question.

Answer (score 1):

In general you better avoid `__built_in_return_address` for arguments bigger than `0`. On many (most?) platforms they will [only work when code is compiled with -fno-omit-frame-pointer](https://github.com/OpenMPToolsInterface/LLVM-openmp/issues/5) (and [likely to segfault](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=8743) on others).

As an alternative, try using one of the standard backtracing libraries e.g. libunwind or libbacktrace.

Comment: @AmninderSingh Just google for "libbacktrace example".